Is a Neo4j UDF compatable with Apache POI?
I'm using Neo4j v 5.21.0 Enterprise on a PC. I've created a User Define Function to create Excel files from a Neo4j cypher query. It works very well when it runs from Maven, producing the Excel with splits, number formatting, multiple worksheets etc. The compiled jar file does not interfere with a re-start of the Neo4j server. However, the log file shows it does not load the UDF and it is not seen in the show function query. I've gotten lots of ideas from ChatGPT, but non solve the problem. Looking for suggestions and examples of code that does work from a jar. Also, any other best practices for getting an Excel from a cypher query. I've used jxl before and am looking for better functionality.

There are APOC Extended procedures that export to excel. You should probably try to use them instead of your own code. To do so, you will have to install the APOC extended plugin.
In particluar, apoc.export.xls.query takes a Cypher query and exports the results to an excel file.

Yes. Thank you! But the APOC extension does single worksheets and, as I recall, does not format the worksheet. Thus, the need for something more sophisticated.

Apache POI does work in a Neo4j User Defined Function!
There is an unknown glitch in the standalone UDF mentioned in the initial question. When I developed it by addition to a working UDF, there was no glitch.
POI has many easy to implement capabilities that enable lots of flexibility. I'm calling the UDF with the cypher query, the output Excel file path, a string that's parsed for column numeric format info, and messages to add at the end of a worksheet. The UDF by default adds a filter to each column for the data rows only.
